# Iterate through the list

Tags: python, list

The transaction csv looks like this and I add them to list as shown below.

```
Bread Milk

Bread Diapers Beer Eggs Beer


[{'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, '': 7}, {'Bread': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6, 'Eggs': 1}, {'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6, 'Cola': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 2, 'Cola': 1, 'Chips': 2, 'Beer': 1, '': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, '': 7}, {'Bread': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Beer': 3, 'Milk': 1, 'Chips': 1, 'Diapers': 3, '': 1}, {'Milk': 1, 'Bread': 1, 'Beer': 4, 'Cola': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Chips': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 2, 'Diapers': 2, 'Beer': 2, 'Chips': 2}, {'Bread': 2, 'Beer': 3, 'Diapers': 3, 'Milk': 1}]
```

I would like to consider only the list which contains the count 3 Diapers.

I would expect the transactions to return only as shown below:

```
{'Bread': 2, 'Beer': 3, 'Diapers': 3, 'Milk': 1}
{'Bread': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Beer': 3, 'Milk': 1, 'Chips': 1, 'Diapers': 3, '': 1}


{'Bread', 'Beer', 'Diapers', 'Milk'}
{'Bread', 'Cola', 'Beer', 'Milk', 'Chips', 'Diapers', ''}
```

The code i have is:

```
def M():
    li = []
    # Open the csv file
    with open('transaction.csv') as fp:
        DataCaptured = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        # Iterate through each word in csv and add it's counter to the row
        for row in DataCaptured:
            li.append(dict(Counter(row)))
            if li['Diaper']==3: ---> I am missing this logic not sure how to get it.

    # Return the list of counters
        return li



print(M())
```

Comment: It's json, not csv.

Comment: @OlvinRoght no JSON here as far as I can tell

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, okay, it's json with single quotes, python dicts. Doesn't matter actually, it's definately not csv and there's no reason to use `csv.reader()` to read this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li=[{'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, '': 7}, {'Bread': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6, 'Eggs': 1}, {'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6, 'Cola': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Beer': 6}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, 'Diapers': 2, 'Cola': 1, 'Chips': 2, 'Beer': 1, '': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 1, '': 7}, {'Bread': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Beer': 3, 'Milk': 1, 'Chips': 1, 'Diapers': 3, '': 1}, {'Milk': 1, 'Bread': 1, 'Beer': 4, 'Cola': 1, 'Diapers': 1, 'Chips': 1}, {'Bread': 1, 'Milk': 2, 'Diapers': 2, 'Beer': 2, 'Chips': 2}, {'Bread': 2, 'Beer': 3, 'Diapers': 3, 'Milk': 1}]
    for d in li:
        if 'Diapers' in d and d['Diapers']==3:
            print(d)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'Bread': 1, 'Cola': 1, 'Beer': 3, 'Milk': 1, 'Chips': 1, 'Diapers': 3, '': 1}
{'Bread': 2, 'Beer': 3, 'Diapers': 3, 'Milk': 1}
```

Comment: What i had to remove those counts? and just display the list?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is that not your desired output?

Comment: Please check the updated expected output without count

Comment: You can just print d.keys()

Comment: It works but i get dict_keys(['Bread', 'Diapers', 'Beer', 'Eggs']), how do i remove dict_keys?

Comment: `list(d.keys())`

Comment: `list(d)` is also the same as `list(d.keys())`